# Select elements from $N$ sets

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

$N$ sets are given which can have any number of elements from $1-100$ each. Now we need to count arrangements in which we select $1$ element from each set under the condition that we can not choose same element from any of the other available sets.

Example: If we had chosen $2$ from the first set, then we cannot choose $2$ from any other set which also contains $2$.

We need to count the number of such possible arrangements where two arrangements are said to be different if their is at least one different element from other arrangements.

Example: Let we have 3 sets $\{ 1, 2, 3 \}, \{ 4 \}, \{ 1, 2 \}$. Here answer will be $4$: the four possible arrangements are $(1,4,2)$, $(2,4,1)$, $(3,4,1)$, and $(3,4,2)$.

Comment: Obviously the answer depends on how the sets intersect each other. Would you be satisfied by a general formula given by the inclusion-exclusion principle or a multivariate generating function?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I would be satisfied if you could provide me a algorithm to do so.Or formula if its possible

Comment: Isn't this a codechef competition problem, the same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885239/distinct-arrangement --- doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the sets are $S_1,\ldots,S_k$, with the inclusion-exclusion principle you can count the number of $k$-uples $(s_1,\ldots,s_k)$ in which $s_i$ belongs to $S_i$, then subtract the number of $k$-uples in which the same $s$ appears at least twice, then add the number of $k$-uples in which the same $s$ appears at least three times an so on. Hence we have the formula:
$$ N = \prod_{j=1}^{k}|S_k|-\sum_{m=2}^{k}\;\;(-1)^m\;\;\cdot\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\sum_{A=\{i_1,\ldots,i_m\}\subseteq\{1,\ldots,k\}}\left(|S_{i_1}\cap\ldots\cap S_{i_m}|\prod_{i\not\in A}|S_i|\right).\tag{1}$$
In your example the only non-empty intersection is the one between $S_1$ and $S_3$, hence:
$$ N = |S_1||S_2||S_3|-|S_1\cap S_3||S_2| = 3\cdot 1\cdot 2-2\cdot 1=4.$$
Obviously, when $k$ is big and many sets intersect non-trivially, to compute $N$ through $(1)$ may become lengthy.

Comment: So is their any method to find these intersecting sets ?

Comment: If say their is set S4 that intersect with S2 and S1 both.Then what will be formula according to you?

Comment: Can i write your formula like as follow : |S1||S2||S3|−|S1∩S2||S3|-|S2∩S3||S1|-|S1∩S3||S2|+|S1∩S2∩S3|?

Comment: If $S_4$ intersect both $S_1$ and $S_2$ and $S_1\cap S_2\neq\emptyset$, by assuming that $S_3$ still intersects $S_1$ but does not intersect $S_4$, we have: $$N=|S_1||S_2||S_3||S_4|-|S_1\cap S_2||S_3||S_4|-|S_1\cap S_4||S_2||S_3|-|S_2\cap S_4||S_1||S_3|+|S_1\cap S_2\cap S_4||S_3|.$$

Comment: And yes, your formula for three sets is correct.

Comment: I am deleting this temporarily. I will undelete when the question is unlocked. ping me if I have not.